# How to make LibreOffice 7.2 toolbar readable?

Tags: user-interface, user-experience, libreoffice, usability-testing

I have installed LibreOffice v7.2 and while it may be functionally OK, I am having extreme trouble actually reading toolbar-s.  Here's an example screenshot:
[image: LibreOffice toolbar]

- Note the circled areas.  These are common toolbar buttons for alignment, indent, etc.
- They are so faint as to be unreadable.
- I have needed to rely on tooltips to figure-out were "common" things are located on the toolbar.

I recently upgraded from LibreOffice 6.7 and all buttons/icons were bright and legible.  I can't imagine why things have gone "*all faded*" in this way.

I am hoping there's a stylesheet or something I can use to tweak the interface.  I hope this is just me, it would be a pity if the GUI is like this out of the box.

I have been looking through help and options panels.  NO luck as yet.

- I'd appreciate it if someone who recognises the situation can point me in the right direction or indentify any options that can restore readability.
- Is this a bug?
- Is this something in default config or something I've inadvertently selected to fade-out icons, etc?
- Could it be something else?

Comment: I never saw this before. Which OS are you using? It might be a system-wide adjustment.

Comment: Tabbed UI is experimental. Does the problem still occur if you switch to standard toolbar? Tabbed does look fine on my Win10 system with version 7.2.2.2 x64.